# Angular 2 : How do you import routerLink exclusively

Tags: javascript, angular

### How do you import the routerLink directive exclusively in Angular 2

**Problem**

I'm making a common module for my app and I use routerLink everywhere but nothing else in the RouterModule so I'm wanting a way to get access to the directive without importing everything.

**What I Know**

I know to get the routerLink directive you need to import the RouterModule, like so.

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

I also know that all modules just import, declare, and export components, service and so on. So in theory the routerLink should be able to be imported directly but I can't find out how.

Comment: In your app.component I guess you have declared some routes using something like `RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: false}),`. That basically provides all the needed router directives for your app. Just add `RouterModule` to your common modules as I would guess routing is going to be a common thing in your app. You will always need the `RouterModule` to be present to use its directives, no point in trying to just import the routerLink directive with no RouterModule?

Comment: you've got a very good point

Comment: I don't think you can use routerLink without importing the whole RouterModule.

Answer (score 2):

Now in 2023 you can import RouterLink):

```
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
```